# Use Promises For Web-Worker With Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, web-worker, redux-thunk

My setup is: Webpack, React, Redux (incl. redux-thunk).

I am working towards integrating web workers in my `mouseMove` eventListener. The need is to find out which elements have a collision with the 'group selection' rect as the user draws in the drawing app.

The call to web-worker is going to be async so, within the action-creator function, I am trying to raise a promise, which upon resolve, calls the payload creating func (resolve) as follows:

**ACTION CREATOR:**

```
export const groupSelectionPayload = ( a, b, c ) => {
    let something = doSomething( a, b );
    return( new Promise( function( resolve, reject ){
        let selectedElements = getSelectedElements( something, c );
        // Im not sure about the below condition,
        //  which I am using to call either resolve / reject funcs,
        //  is there a better way to handle this?
        if( selectedElements !== undefined ){
            resolve( something );
        } else {
            reject();
        }
    }));
};

// when promise resolves, we return the action to dispatch
const resolve = function( rectCoOrd ){
    return ({
        type : CREATE_GROUP_SELECTION_RECT,
        svgPayload : {
            curToolbarCtrlSelection : {
                ctrlName : "grpSelect",
                props : {
                    pos : {
                        x : rectCoOrd[ 0 ],
                        y : rectCoOrd[ 1 ],
                        w : rectCoOrd[ 2 ],
                        h : rectCoOrd[ 3 ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
};

// func posts message to web-worker
const getSelectedElements = ( something, c ) => {
    worker_handler.postMessage( iMap({
        type : "grpSelect",
    }));
};
```

I am using Redux-thunk for async, yet, I get the error: 
`Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` Followed by:
`uncaught exception : undefined`

What am I doing wrong and is there a more sensible way to go about handling the scenario discussed above?

**Edit:**
I needed to install [redux-promise](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise) middleware which I have.

```
const store = createStore( reducer, composeEnhancer( applyMiddleware( thunk, promiseMiddleware )));
```

... which has resolved the `Actions must be plain objects ...` error. However, I am still getting the `uncaught exception : undefined` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess your action creator should look like so:

```
export const groupSelectionPayload = ( a, b, c ) => dispatch => {
  //do some async stuff like so:

  new Promise((res, rej) => { … })
    .then(data => dispatch({type: 'success', payload: { data }}))
    .catch(error => dispatch({type: 'error', payload: { error }}))
}
```

Redux thunk will call the method returned from the creator with dispatch as parameter. So within that method you can dispatch other actions, when the async stuff is done, or before, or on progress.

Additionally redux thunk will return the value of the function supplied by the action creator. So can also:

```
const someAction = id => dispatch => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  const result = something(id);
  if (result !== null) {
    dispatch({type: 'success', payload: { result }})
    res(result);
  } else { … }

});
```

And in the component you than:

```
this.props.action(<id>).then(/*getting fancy here, update State or something*/);
```

But when you are dealing with a webWorker, I think middleware would be a better place to put the code:

```
const customMiddleware = store => {
  //create and connect to the worker here
  const worker = …
  worker.onmessage = msg => store.dispatch({type: 'workermsg', payload: {msg}});
  return next => action => {
    if(action.type !== 'posttoworker') return next(action)
    worker.postMessage(action.payload.msg)
  }
}
```

I have not taken care too much about the worker code, its just about the idea, to use middle as api for the worker…

Comment: this is a wonderful answer & a lot for me to think / take in. I dont need web-worker for all tasks, hence not thinking of integrating it as a middleware. In addition, I may be needing multiple web-workers for different tasks, e.g. collision between elements, when user adds a new element to canvas with already filled elements (checking an element's coordinates against a few thousand elements is heavy)...

Comment: I think you missunderstood the concept of middleware a bit. With it you kind of subscribe to certain actions of interest, all others just pass through. Basically you could provide one middleware for each worker.

Comment: Then I certainly did. I have actually spent the morning understanding the middleware code. And this comment of yours further cements that I need to understand this thoroughly. I'll raise another question once Im ready for this & hopefully you will come across it :). Thanks a million for the continuous feedback, its immensely helpful! Best,

Comment: Have a look at redux thunk middleware. It is the simplest thing and shows the concept.